# how to pass props to initial state in useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having an issue with initialising a useState hook with props that is passed to the current component from another.

the areas where I am having the issue is below (Keep in mind that I can access the prop if i just console.log it, so it not a matter of a failure of the prop passing data down)

```
const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState('');
```

It is important for me to pass the props like below as my data fetching on this component depends on Uid. So far I have tried

```
const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState(props.uid);
```

this did not work as it told me- first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

```
const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState(props);

        useEffect(() => {
            setUid(props.uid);
        }, []);
```

Can anyone see where i might be going wrong?

the full code is here- https://www.codepile.net/pile/m3zmwnK1

remember, the most important thing for me is to have the Uid contain the value from the props.uid as otherwise react gives me a "first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined" issue

Comment: Please show a producible example - how you call the component, show us how you passing the `uid` prop and the rest **minimal** working component.

Comment: Done mate. I also added the full code

Comment: This code doesn't help, *how you pass* `uid`?

Comment: as a prop from the app.js--->  <Home uid={uid} />

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring props.uid in subsequent effects. Try this

```
const Component({uid}){
 const [stateUid, setUid] = useState(uid);

useEffect(()=>{
 setUid(uid);
},[uid])

}
```

Comment: Is above syntax confusing ? writing const Component({uid, ...rest}) is same as writing const Component(props). And then you can access props.uid. Please inform if issue is something else.

Comment: I am meeting with this error mate- Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined

Comment: after trying your solution

Comment: That error you mentioned is not related to React though. Seems like it is firebase error. Try to wrap your API calls in try catch and see if React code is breaking yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add props to your `useEffect` dependency. If it changes too often, u might drop into infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUid(props.uid);
}, [props.uid]);
```

In you App.js

```
function App() {
const [ user, setuser ] = useState(false);
const [ uid, setUid ] = useState(); //initial is empty

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChange();
    return () => {
        unsubscribe();
    };
}, []); // it only run once so it might not set the state of uid

return <div className="App">{user ? <Home uid={uid} /> : <Form />}</div>; 
// uid passing to Home component might be empty
```

Comment: can you elaborate mate? All i want to do is feed the props as the initial state the hook like const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState(props.uid); . When i insert the string from the prop like const [ Uid, setUid ] = useState('jYAhV0xCtmOEJtOPXHirYXkQtju1'); it works. but when the string is replaced by props.uid, Uid appears to be undefined

Comment: The problem is the props might not finish loading in store State since it is async func. So the useState will only initialize the first state of props.uid which could be undefined. So, setting useEffect, will update the Uid after the first load and update/change only the props.uid is modified

Comment: I understand mate, but trying this didnt work as well :/

Comment: You might wanna update your full code and i can have a look. btw, you should change Uid to uid instead. React treat first capital letter of a variable as a component.

Comment: the code is here mate- https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vwd1pa50 :)